# Can I get notified when Visual Studio discovers external changes?

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm developing a Visual Studio extension. I would like to get a callback when Visual Studio discovers that files in the open solution have been modified externally and need to be reloaded. Is there anything like that?

Comment: Are you looking for the Running Document Table (RDT): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/subscribing-to-an-event

Comment: Thanks for the tip @SimonMourier! I'm new to the Visual Studio SDK, but the Running Document Table (RDT) seems to keep track of the running/open documents. I need to know when Visual Studio has detected externally modified files that it has to reload.

To give more context to this: I'm changing git branch externally, and need to wait until Visual Studio has realized that there are changes that need to be loaded.

Comment: The RDT is a facility that any package can use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/running-document-table?view=vs-2019#other-uses-of-the-running-document-table . A file must be reloaded if it's known by Visual Studio. If it's known then it will be in the RDT. If it's not in the RDT, it's not open, so it doesn't need to be reloaded. You can use this sample to check what's in the RDT: https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/RunningDocumentTable(RDT)_Event_Explorer

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, it's very much appreciated! I followed the walkthrough (that you posted in the first comment) and implemented the code. The events I received were regarding the opening and closing of the documents. I'll run the sample you linked to and see what I can dig out from there. Thanks again!

Comment: "If it's not in the RDT, it's not open, so it doesn't need to be reloaded." - In my tests, an externally modified file will be reloaded and integrated into the VisualStudioWorkspace, even if it isn't open, so there appears to be some other mechanic that recognizes the external change and starts a process.

Comment: To give more context on why I'm looking for this, as it's part of a bigger problem: I'm writing a Visual Studio extension that performs git commands, I need to know that Visual Studio has picked up on the changes on disk, before I proceed to the next operation.

Comment: "open" does not mean visually open, but just "put in the RDT". Also, don't confuse Visual Studio (RDT) and Roslyn (Workspaces). Otherwise, note that everything in Visual Studio is a plugin (package, etc.). Each plugin can eventually do its own stuff. Git is a plugin that can do things not necessarily accessible to other plugins. Difficult to say more without details.

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier, I appreciate the help. I'm not confusing "Visual Studio (RDT) and Roslyn (Workspaces)" but it's a good distinction to make. I use the Roslyn VisualStudioWorkspace to perform an analysis on the solution. I've tried the RDT events I can find, but I have not yet found a way to get notified when a file in the solution has been modified externally. I'll read more about RDT and the Visual Studio SDK.